# Meteor trigger event on server collection change

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I would like to trigger an event on a meteor server when a document on my collection changes to a specific value, say some field changes from false to true.

I am familiar with binding events to the client; however, I want this event to only be called when the server state changes, specifically the value of a given document in my collection. I want to trigger an external HTTP call from the server when this happens, as I need to message external applications.

Comment: Hi, Jab. I'm trying to trigger an event to send an email when a particular collection is updated. Did you manage to do that?

Comment: @buenoFelipe No, I haven't managed to do it yet. The way I got around this simply bind all methods that would attempt to change the collection to call a Meteor.method on the server (via Meteor.call) before attempting to change the collection. The Meteor.method would contain functionality that I'd put in the event (in this case the email sending functionality)

Comment: @buenoFelipe You could also try playing around with cursor.observeChanges(). http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe

Comment: Hey jab...I am also looking for an event which will get trigger whenever there occur any change in database related to any field. Have you found any thing like this..which intimates you that database has been updated ?

Answer (score 1):

Also a bit late, but the most classic solution to this type of problem is using the very popular [meteor-collection-hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) library. In particular, you'd probably want to use the [.after.update](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks#afterupdateuserid-doc-fieldnames-modifier-options) hook (click link for full documentation), which allows you to hook into a particular collection after an update is made to a document and compare before and after by comparing `doc` (doc after update) to `this.previous` (doc before update).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is an old post. For the benefit of others.

Peerdb package seems to do some of the tasks you are looking for. 
https://atmospherejs.com/peerlibrary/peerdb